# Microsoft Windows Server 2016: How can I switch domain names on click in a multi-language website?

Tags: .net, windows, iis, server, cross-domain

I have created a multi-language application and I want to host it on an IIS Server. I have created 2 Websites (one for French (`frenchsite.com` and one for English `englishsite.com`). Now if I'm on my English website and I click on French, how can it redirect me to my French domain?

Let's say I'm on my English index page:

```
englishsite.com/en/index.html
```

When I press on a button, it redirects me to my French website:

```
frenchsite.com/fr/index.html
```

On apache I would do this with a config file, but I don't know where I can find such thing with IIS.

**I am using Microsoft Windows Server 2016**

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell us which apache setting you have used to achieve this requirement?

In my opinion, this could be easily achieved by using a tag or  js function. If you use js function, you could bind a button onclick function to redirect to another IIS web sites.

Details, you could refer to below codes.

```
        <a href="http://frenchsite.com/fr/index.html">French</a>
```

or

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            location.href = "http://frenchsite.com/fr/index.html";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <a  onclick="myFunction()">French</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```